# Embed Google Analytics on thrid-part website

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, embed

Trying to embed GA report on a third-part website, and I follow the Demo on Google Developers website, although I have some (silly) questions and I'm having trouble figuring it out.

After got clientid and put it my page I got exactly the same page as in google's example.

[image]

When I sent the link to someone else, it grabbed the info from the properties from  people's GA I sent the link to, not my website.

Can someone help me set the property and eliminate the dropdowns to choose Account, Property, Views?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is to do user authorization server-side. This will allow you to show Google Analytics data on your website without requiring your visitors to log in.

You can view the [Embed API Service-Side Auth demo](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) to see a working example.